# How to export N records from each table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

The problem is my database is more than 30GB in size ( Live Server ) , In order for me to fix a bug in my local machine, I want to download database making sure, it only exports first 10 records from each table. ( As If I download 30 GB it would slow down the process and won't be a good approach )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a normal mysqldum and add a Where Clause

```
mysqldump -t -u root -p  mytestdb mytable --where='id<1000000'
```

or you can use as well

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'data_path.sql' from mytable where id<100000
```

There Where clause can be a little difficult.